# Showing or hiding a button based on contents of a field in a database

Tags: ios, database, if-statement, titanium-mobile

I am trying to show or hide a button based on the contents of a particular database field. I have the field defined as 'text', as the field may contain something like 1-1 or 1-20 or 0. If the field (arref1) is not equal to 0 then I want to show my button. Otherwise hide the button. Here is what I have so far but it dosen't work:

```
var resultRule = db.execute('SELECT arref1 FROM genrules WHERE title="'+client+'"');
if (resultRule!='0') {

var appliedRule1 = Ti.UI.createButton({
title:' Applied Rule ' + rows.fieldByName('arref1') + '',
bottom:120,
left: 80,
width: 'auto',
height:40,
borderRadius:5,
textAlign: 'center',
color:'#FFFFFF',
backgroundColor:'#7b4336',
backgroundSelectedColor:'#cc9933',
backgroundImage: 'NONE',
font:{fontSize:'20dp'}
});
win.add(appliedRule1);

appliedRule1.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{

    var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        url: 'appliedruledetail.js',
        title:' Applied Rule' + rows.fieldByName('arref1') + ''
    });

    var client = '' + rows.fieldByName('genrule') + '' ;
    win.client = client;
    Ti.UI.currentTab.open(win);
}

);
} else{};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`db.execute` returns a [`Titanium.DB.ResultSet`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Database.ResultSet) (which is an object) not a string.

Here is how you use a result set:

```
// Get the row with execute, returns a resultSet
var row = db.execute('SELECT * FROM genrules WHERE title="'+client+'"');
// Make sure its a valid row
if (row.isValidRow()){ 
  // Now get the field from the current row
  if(row.fieldByName('arref1') != '0') {
       // Add your button here
  }
}
row.close(); // Close the result set since were done with it
```

[I heavily borrowed from this example in the documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/api/Titanium.Database.ResultSet)

Comment: I think we've got the mail at the same time. Was about to answer this ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, I learned about ResultSet and working with them.